# Hue service in hadoop environment crashes after few seconds

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, hue

I am just starting out with hadoop and I followed [this](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-easily-install-hadoop-with-docker-ad094d556f11) article to install an hadoop environment with docker-compose.

Unfortunately, it seems like hue service is crashing and I cannot access any UIs (not even the namenode UI. I am running the following commands in Ubuntu 20.04 inside WSL2:

```
git clone https://github.com/m-semnani/bd-infra.git
cd bd-infra
docker-compose up -d
```

Then, after everything is installed and the services are up and running, I do a simple docker ps and see the following results:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                                                      NAMES
d1cac433a6ee        bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore           "entrypoint.sh /bin/…"   6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds                      0.0.0.0:10000->10000/tcp, 10002/tcp                        hive-server
603604a7ce37        bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore           "entrypoint.sh /opt/…"   7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                      10000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9083->9083/tcp, 10002/tcp               hive-metastore
9964d2f49f5b        bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds                      5432/tcp                                                   hive-metastore-postgresql
494f5edaed7e        bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.7              "/bin/bash /worker.sh"   8 seconds ago       Up 6 seconds                      0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                                     spark-worker
3d42461686fb        gethue/hue:20191107-135001                        "./startup.sh"           8 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds                      0.0.0.0:8888->8888/tcp                                     hue
ef5213648cee        bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   9 seconds ago       Up 7 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:50075->50075/tcp                                   datanode
82dc9e4ab2ab        bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds (health: starting)   0.0.0.0:50070->50070/tcp                                   namenode
51271761043f        wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.3.0                     "start-kafka.sh"         10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds                      0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                     bd-infra_kafka_1
8c6f51379a48        bde2020/spark-master:2.4.0-hadoop2.7              "/bin/bash /master.sh"   10 seconds ago      Up 8 seconds                      0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 6066/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   spark-master
b8ca46f10106        wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6                      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   10 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds                      22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp         bd-infra_zookeeper_1
```

As we can see, the hue service is running is up and running with container ID 3d42461686fb. However, after I wait a few seconds and do docker ps again, I see that the hue container is not running anymore:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                                      NAMES
d1cac433a6ee        bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore           "entrypoint.sh /bin/…"   29 seconds ago      Up 28 seconds             0.0.0.0:10000->10000/tcp, 10002/tcp                        hive-server
603604a7ce37        bde2020/hive:2.3.2-postgresql-metastore           "entrypoint.sh /opt/…"   30 seconds ago      Up 29 seconds             10000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9083->9083/tcp, 10002/tcp               hive-metastore
9964d2f49f5b        bde2020/hive-metastore-postgresql:2.3.0           "/docker-entrypoint.…"   31 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds             5432/tcp                                                   hive-metastore-postgresql
494f5edaed7e        bde2020/spark-worker:2.4.0-hadoop2.7              "/bin/bash /worker.sh"   31 seconds ago      Up 30 seconds             0.0.0.0:8081->8081/tcp                                     spark-worker
ef5213648cee        bde2020/hadoop-datanode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   32 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds (healthy)   0.0.0.0:50075->50075/tcp                                   datanode
82dc9e4ab2ab        bde2020/hadoop-namenode:2.0.0-hadoop2.7.4-java8   "/entrypoint.sh /run…"   33 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds (healthy)   0.0.0.0:50070->50070/tcp                                   namenode
51271761043f        wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.3.0                     "start-kafka.sh"         33 seconds ago      Up 32 seconds             0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                     bd-infra_kafka_1
8c6f51379a48        bde2020/spark-master:2.4.0-hadoop2.7              "/bin/bash /master.sh"   33 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds             0.0.0.0:7077->7077/tcp, 6066/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   spark-master
b8ca46f10106        wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6                      "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   33 seconds ago      Up 31 seconds             22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp         bd-infra_zookeeper_1
```

Also, when I try to access the UI of the namenode on localhost:50070 and the UI of hue on localhost:8888, I get the error This site can’t be reached (which is obviously the case for the hue service, but surprisingly also for the namenode.)

The only thing I changed compared to the repo's docker-compose file is that I changed the volume path /tmp into ./tmp in the docker-compose file, but I am getting the same problem in either case. Do you have any recommendations how to fix this issue?

Update 1:
Below are the logs of the hue container of a few seconds after running `docker-compose up --build -d` and then `docker-compose logs hue`:

```
Attaching to hue
hue                          | [21/Mar/2021 10:38:00 ] settings     INFO     Welcome to Hue 4.5.0
hue                          | [21/Mar/2021 03:38:04 -0700] decorators   INFO     AXES: BEGIN LOG
hue                          | [21/Mar/2021 03:38:04 -0700] decorators   INFO     Using django-axes 2.2.0
hue                          | Traceback (most recent call last):
hue                          |   File "./build/env/bin/hue", line 11, in <module>
hue                          |     load_entry_point('desktop', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 225, in entry
hue                          |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
hue                          |     utility.execute()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
hue                          |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
hue                          |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
hue                          |     self.check()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
hue                          |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
hue                          |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
hue                          |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
hue                          |     errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 1284, in check
hue                          |     errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 1359, in _check_fields
hue                          |     errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 913, in check
hue                          |     errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 219, in check
hue                          |     errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 322, in _check_backend_specific_checks
hue                          |     return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 49, in check_field
hue                          |     field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 644, in db_type
hue                          |     return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
hue                          |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 174, in data_types
hue                          |     if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
hue                          |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
hue                          |     return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
hue                          |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 385, in mysql_version
hue                          |     with self.temporary_connection() as cursor:
hue                          |   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
hue                          |     return self.gen.next()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 591, in temporary_connection
hue                          |     cursor = self.cursor()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
hue                          |     return self._cursor()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
hue                          |     self.ensure_connection()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
hue                          |     self.connect()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
hue                          |     six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
hue                          |     self.connect()
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
hue                          |     self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.11.22-py2.7.egg/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 274, in get_new_connection
hue                          |     conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
hue                          |     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
hue                          |   File "/usr/share/hue/build/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.5-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
hue                          |     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
hue                          | django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'database' (0)")
```

There are actually more logs, but they are just a repititon of the above. As suggested in the comments, it does seem like there is a database connection error. My initial thought was that maybe there is something wrong in the `database` section of the [hue-overrides.ini](https://github.com/m-semnani/bd-infra/blob/master/hue-overrides.ini) file, but the host and port name seem to make sense to me. If anyone could share some more insights on this, I'd highly appreciate it.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Please share the logs of the Hue container, most probably it could not connect to its database.

Comment: Hi @Romain thanks a lot for your interest. As requested, I updated the question with the logs of the Hue container.

Comment: And now it seems like you need to make the docker-compose know about your local database (or also boot a 'datatabase' in the docker-compose)

Comment: Dear @Romain, I'm not sure I completely follow. In this [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/m-semnani/bd-infra/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) file, there is already a database service from a mysql image which is probably meant as a database backend for the hue service. Could you elaborate more on what you meant?